# SQL Select Statement issue - returning rows conditionally on a 2nd table

Tags: sql

I could really use some help with the following SQL Select statement scenario:

I need to select all rows from a table conditionally depending on whether a userID has already entered data into a second table with the same ID.

Example:

1. Select all rows from TABLE A for idNumber where idNumber not in
   TABLE B
2. but for each idNumber that IS in TABLE B, still return row unless a
   specific userID is in that row in TABLE B.

---

```
TABLE A
========
idNumber|type|Date

   1      A    01/01/01

   2      A    01/01/01

   3      B    01/01/01

   4      B    01/01/01

   5      B    01/01/01

TABLE B
========
idNumber|type|userID
   1      A    0000

   3      B    0000

   4      B    1111
```

userID to exclude records for = 1111

SQL Query should return:

```
idNumber|type|Date

   1      A    01/01/01

   2      A    01/01/01

   3      B    01/01/01

   5      B    01/01/01
```

Apologies for the long winded post but i hope it makes sense.

Many thanks in advance,
ukjezza.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select idNumber, type, Date
From TableA
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From TableB
                    Where TableB.idNumber = TableA.idNumber
                        And TableB.userID = 1111
                    )
```

Another choice:

```
Select TableA.idNumber, TableA.type, TableA.Date
From TableA
    Left Join TableB
        On TableB.idNumber = TableA.idNumber
            And TableB.userId = 1111
Where TableB.idNumber Is Null
```

Comment: Do you know how the performance of this compares to using `JOIN`s?

Comment: @Abe Miessler - Depends on the database and the nature of the data. If TableB is ginormous compared to TableA, the Exists clause will perform better (again, depending on the db). If both tables are about the same size, then the Join will likely perform better. I've noticed that SQL Server handles Exists functions better than say MySQL. MySQL wants an In clause instead of an Exists function.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` could take care of it:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TableA as a
LEFT JOIN TableB as b
ON a.idNumber = b.idNumber
WHERE COALESCE(b.userID, -1) != 1111
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.*
from TableA as A
  left outer join TableB as B
    on A.idNumber = B.idNumber
where B.idNumber is null or
      B.userID <> '1111'
```

Comment: Thank you all so much guys, i now have a solution AND i have learned many new ways of selecting data conditionally.

I actually went with:
Select idNumber, type,
DateFrom TableAWhere Not Exists
(Select 1 From TableB 
Where TableB.idNumber = bleA.idNumber
And TableB.userID = 1111)

Thanks again!!!!